# linux - disabling and enabling link-local

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to find out how to disable and enable link local addresses, on my linux machine(also on arm). So basically for IPv4 and IPv6 I would like to either disable (or bring down) both addresses together or even individually if needs be. Then to enable both again. I would also like to check if they have been disabled and enabled each time.

Is it possible to execute system command line scripts to achieve this, for instance

```
*ip -f inet route*  or
*ip -f inet6 route*
```

Is it possible to do this without restarting the network?

Also, I have, using the 2 examples above, obtained both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. For example,

```
ip -f inet route | grep \"dev eth0\" | cut -d' ' -f1
ip -f inet route | grep \"dev eth0\" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

but I am concerned that the grep string is not unique enough to search for the line(s) where the address(es) are. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Provided you know that you have a certain link-local address, you use `ip addr del fe80::xyzfillinhere dev eth0`, not `ip -f inet route`.

Answer (score 0):

`ip link set lo down` ?
you can operate with adresses with `ip addr` too